# can't get Youtube video with pytube library

Tags: python, pytube

I coding a youtube video downloader
if I using `Youtube()` to get video it's doesn't work

my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7F40MVG0Wc")
print(yt.title)
stream = yt.streams.first()
stream.download()
```

in the third line I get a lot of errors

errors I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects\Youtube Video Downloader\index5.py", line 3, in <module>
    yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7F40MVG0Wc")
```

How can me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please confirm that you are on the latest version of pytube by installing from the source.

You can do this by running `python -m pip install git+https://github.com/pytube/pytube` Sometimes, the pypi library repository is not up to date, and your issue may have been fixed already!

In `C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py`

Change this line:

293:  `name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))`

to this:

293: `name = "iha"`

this Solution is mentioned in Github issues and it's working fine.

Here is an example:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os
from pathlib import Path


url = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-9MaAW_9dY')

print("downloading....")

video = url.streams.get_highest_resolution()

path_to_download_folder = str(os.path.join(Path.home(), "Downloads"))

video.download(path_to_download_folder)
print("Downloaded! :)")
```